# I want to return 2 objects. How can I do that?

Tags: apex

I am not getting how to write the return statement. I want to return both `schemaMap` and `fieldMap`. Here is my code.

```
public class ObjectAll {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getObjectAPI() {
    List<String> objectAPI = new List<String>();
    return objectAPI;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String,String> getFieldNames() {
    String query = '';
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for(String fieldName : fieldMap.keyset()){
        query = fieldName + ',' + query;
    }

    System.debug('---------------->> a ' + query);

    return ;
}

}
```

Comment: Serialize each of them into JSON and add it in list of String. And then simply return that list

Answer (score 6):

You just need to declare another class as a wrapper. Then, you just return a new instance of this class.

Here's the right code:

```
public class ObjectAll {
    //The wrapper class
    public class Wrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> SchemaMap {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> FieldMap {get; set;}
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getObjectAPI() {
        List<String> objectAPI = new List<String>();
        return objectAPI;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Wrapper getFieldNames() {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();

        String query = '';
        wrapper.SchemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        wrapper.FieldMap = schemaMap.get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        for(String fieldName : wrapper.FieldMap.keyset()){
            query = fieldName + ',' + query;
        }

        System.debug('---------------->> a ' + query);

        return wrapper;
    }

}
```